# why my program stops working when type enter?

Tags: c

My main goal for this code is to capture the users input and do whatever he wants to do with the choices I have presented, but I'm stuck: when I compile, I can only type the word and the program stops working.

i have no idea where I'm making a mistake.

The is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100

void grab_user_input(void);
void load_menu(void);
void Count_the_letters(void);

int main(void)
{
    grab_user_input();
    return 0;
}

void grab_user_input(void)
{
    char word;
    {
        printf("Please enter a single word (25 characters or less): \n");
        scanf("%s", &word);
        printf("Thanks! The word you entered is: %s\n", word);
    }

    void load_menu(void)
    {
        int choice;
        do
        {
            int choice;
            printf("\n(:===Menu====:)\n");
            printf("1. Count_the_letters\n");
            printf("2. Count_the_vowels\n");
            printf("3. Reverse_the_word\n");
            printf("4. Check_if_palindrome\n");
            printf("5. Enter_a_new_word\n");
            printf("6.     Exit\n");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1: Count_the_letters();
            break;

            }
        } while (choice != 3);
    }

    void Count_the_letters(void)
    {
        char S[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        int  count;

        count = 0;

        do {
            printf("string:\t");
            scanf("%s",S);
            if (strcmp(S,"exit") != 0)
                ++count;
        } while (strcmp(S,"exit") != 0);

        printf("word count:\t%d\n", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that your exact code? Where are you learning c from?

Comment: yes thats my code im learning code by my self @iharob

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%s", &word);
```

needs an array of characters to read the data. `&word` only has space for one character.

You are running into undefined behavior.

Use

```
char word[26];
scanf("%25s", &word);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are passing the address to the `char` variable you declared and `scanf()` is trying to write two bytes where it only fits one.

```
char word
```

this declares a `char` variable, it can hold a single byte

```
scanf("%s", &word);
```

whill require at least one byte for an empty string the `'\0'`.

But also, you declared a lot of functions inside `void grab_user_input(void)`, that is not valid standard c, it might work with some compiler, but it's not standard.